# Get valid rows based on month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with standard structure

```
| Some_Data| Valid_from | Valid_to |
|---- |------| -----|
| One  | 1.1.2008| 16.7.2022|
| One  | 1.1.2015| 16.7.2021|
| One  | 1.1.2015| 13.7.2015|
| One  | 1.1.2017| 1.7.2018|
```

Now if I wanted to get records that are valid today I would do

```
select * from table
where 1=1
and trunc(sydate) between valid_from and valid_to
```

But in my case I need to query records that are valid in this month. I tried to do

```
select * from table
where 1=1
and to_char(trunc(sydate), 'MM/YYYY') between to_char(valid_from, 'MM/YYYY') and to_char(valid_to, 'MM/YYYY')
```

But this does not work correctly (it will return all records).

Is there any way how to get records valid in a month not in a particular date?

Thanks for sharing an anaswer

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd attempt doesn't work because you're comparing strings (and not dates).

I'd try

```
where trunc(sysdate, 'mm') between trunc(valid_from, 'mm') 
                               and trunc(valid_to  , 'mm')
```

For example (with modified data you posted, as it is invalid for this example - no rows contains `sysdate`; the 4th row seems to be *backwards* (`from` is larger than `to`).

```
SQL> with test (some_date, valid_from, valid_to) as
  2    (select 'one', date '2008-01-01', date '2022-09-16' from dual union all
  3     select 'one', date '2015-01-01', date '2021-07-16' from dual union all
  4     select 'one', date '2015-01-01', date '2015-07-13' from dual union all
  5     select 'one', date '2017-01-01', date '2021-07-01' from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where trunc(sysdate, 'mm') between trunc(valid_from, 'mm')
 10                                 and trunc(valid_to  , 'mm')
 11  /

SOM VALID_FROM VALID_TO
--- ---------- ----------
one 01.01.2008 16.09.2022

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Indeed 4th line was wrong so I edited it. The naswer you provided seems to be working. Is trunc(date, mm) same as trunc(date, MM)? Cant find any documentation on 'mm'?

Comment: Letter case is irrelevant here, both mm and MM represent *month*.